# Unable to understand the coredump gdb output - Segmentation Fault

Tags: node.js, segmentation-fault, gdb

I came across a weird problem. I have a node app that works fine in most environments. But only on one of the instances it randomly throws a Segmentation Fault and crash. I could pull the core dump and run it with GDB and the following is the output.

```
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0 0x00007f3a561b1be6 in elf_machine_rela (reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, skip_ifunc=0,
  reloc_addr_arg=0x7f3a22bcdfb0, version=0xa8, sym=0x7f3a229b7850, map=0x6e4eb80) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:299
299    struct link_map *sym_map = RESOLVE_MAP (&sym, version, r_type);
(gdb) bt
#0 0x00007f3a561b1be6 in elf_machine_rela (reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, skip_ifunc=0,
  reloc_addr_arg=0x7f3a22bcdfb0, version=0xa8, sym=0x7f3a229b7850, map=0x6e4eb80) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:299
#1 elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=0, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, relsize=<optimized out>,
  reladdr=<optimized out>, map=0x6e4eb80) at do-rel.h:137
#2 _dl_relocate_object (scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=reloc_mode@entry=1, consider_profiling=<optimized out>,
  consider_profiling@entry=0) at dl-reloc.c:259
#3 0x00007f3a561ba66c in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7ffecd303ff8) at dl-open.c:423
#4 0x00007f3a561b57d4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=objname@entry=0x7ffecd303fe8, errstring=errstring@entry=0x7ffecd303ff0,
  mallocedp=mallocedp@entry=0x7ffecd303fe0, operate=operate@entry=0x7f3a561ba160 <dl_open_worker>,
  args=args@entry=0x7ffecd303ff8) at dl-error.c:177
#5 0x00007f3a561b9b8b in _dl_open (file=0x7f3a5531fc06 "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=-2147483647, caller_dlopen=<optimized out>,
  nsid=-2, argc=4, argv=0x7ffecd306928, env=0x7ffecd306950) at dl-open.c:649
#6 0x00007f3a552d5952 in do_dlopen (ptr=ptr@entry=0x7ffecd304200) at dl-libc.c:87
#7 0x00007f3a561b57d4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x7ffecd3041e0, errstring=0x7ffecd3041f0, mallocedp=0x7ffecd3041d0,
  operate=0x7f3a552d5910 <do_dlopen>, args=0x7ffecd304200) at dl-error.c:177
#8 0x00007f3a552d5a12 in dlerror_run (args=0x7ffecd304200, operate=0x7f3a552d5910 <do_dlopen>) at dl-libc.c:46
#9 __GI___libc_dlopen_mode (name=name@entry=0x7f3a5531fc06 "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=mode@entry=-2147483647) at dl-libc.c:163
#10 0x00007f3a552acc05 in init () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/backtrace.c:52
#11 0x00007f3a5556c20b in __pthread_once_slow (once_control=0x7f3a55563cc0 <once.7829>, init_routine=0x7f3a552acbf0 <init>)
  at pthread_once.c:117
#12 0x00007f3a552acd1c in __GI___backtrace (array=<optimized out>, size=256) at ../sysdeps/x86_64/backtrace.c:101
#13 0x0000000000b8db16 in ?? ()
#14 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I tried looking for clues in this and found several references to GNU C compile. Also the last line shows an address like 0x00000000000000 which feels like internally some code is trying to work with a null reference. I am absolutely new to this and looking for help to decipher this output. How to read and make sense of this output? Can we deduce from here what specific problem is causing the segmentation fault.

Node - 16.14.0

Linux Centos7

Issue occurs randomly

Edit: Added output of bt

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007f3a561b1be6 in elf_machine_rela (reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, reloc=0x7f3a229b9fd8, skip_ifunc=0, 
    reloc_addr_arg=0x7f3a22bcdfb0, version=0xa8, sym=0x7f3a229b7850, map=0x6e4eb80)
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h:299
#1  elf_dynamic_do_Rela (skip_ifunc=0, lazy=<optimized out>, nrelative=<optimized out>, 
    relsize=<optimized out>, reladdr=<optimized out>, map=0x6e4eb80) at do-rel.h:137
#2  _dl_relocate_object (scope=<optimized out>, reloc_mode=reloc_mode@entry=1, 
    consider_profiling=<optimized out>, consider_profiling@entry=0) at dl-reloc.c:259
#3  0x00007f3a561ba66c in dl_open_worker (a=a@entry=0x7ffecd303ff8) at dl-open.c:423
#4  0x00007f3a561b57d4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=objname@entry=0x7ffecd303fe8, 
    errstring=errstring@entry=0x7ffecd303ff0, mallocedp=mallocedp@entry=0x7ffecd303fe0, 
    operate=operate@entry=0x7f3a561ba160 <dl_open_worker>, args=args@entry=0x7ffecd303ff8) at dl-error.c:177
#5  0x00007f3a561b9b8b in _dl_open (file=0x7f3a5531fc06 "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=-2147483647, 
    caller_dlopen=<optimized out>, nsid=-2, argc=4, argv=0x7ffecd306928, env=0x7ffecd306950) at dl-open.c:649
#6  0x00007f3a552d5952 in do_dlopen (ptr=ptr@entry=0x7ffecd304200) at dl-libc.c:87
#7  0x00007f3a561b57d4 in _dl_catch_error (objname=0x7ffecd3041e0, errstring=0x7ffecd3041f0, 
    mallocedp=0x7ffecd3041d0, operate=0x7f3a552d5910 <do_dlopen>, args=0x7ffecd304200) at dl-error.c:177
#8  0x00007f3a552d5a12 in dlerror_run (args=0x7ffecd304200, operate=0x7f3a552d5910 <do_dlopen>)
    at dl-libc.c:46
#9  __GI___libc_dlopen_mode (name=name@entry=0x7f3a5531fc06 "libgcc_s.so.1", mode=mode@entry=-2147483647)
    at dl-libc.c:163
#10 0x00007f3a552acc05 in init () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/backtrace.c:52
#11 0x00007f3a5556c20b in __pthread_once_slow (once_control=0x7f3a55563cc0 <once.7829>, 
    init_routine=0x7f3a552acbf0 <init>) at pthread_once.c:117
#12 0x00007f3a552acd1c in __GI___backtrace (array=<optimized out>, size=256)
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/backtrace.c:101
#13 0x0000000000b8db16 in report::WriteNodeReport(v8::Isolate*, node::Environment*, char const*, char const*, std::string const&, std::ostream&, v8::Local<v8::Value>, bool) ()
#14 0x0000000000b8f596 in report::GetNodeReport(v8::Isolate*, node::Environment*, char const*, char const*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, std::ostream&) ()
#15 0x0000000000b9286f in report::GetReport(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) ()
#16 0x0000000000d53cfe in v8::internal::MaybeHandle<v8::internal::Object> v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::HandleApiCallHelper<false>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::HeapObject>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::FunctionTemplateInfo>, v8::internal::Han---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
dle<v8::internal::Object>, v8::internal::BuiltinArguments) ()
#17 0x0000000000d5511f in v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) ()
#18 0x00000000015f0b79 in Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_BuiltinExit ()
#19 0x000000000158354a in Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline ()
#20 0x000011f747981599 in ?? ()
#21 0x000038a831b4a331 in ?? ()
#22 0x0000000600000000 in ?? ()
#23 0x000011f747981669 in ?? ()
#24 0x00003236f9211e49 in ?? ()
#25 0x0000254fb060b501 in ?? ()
#26 0x00003236f9211e49 in ?? ()
#27 0x000038a831b4a331 in ?? ()
#28 0x0000382929d020f9 in ?? ()
#29 0x0000006300000000 in ?? ()
#30 0x00001e70d09646a1 in ?? ()
#31 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

output from info shared:

```
(gdb) info shared
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007f3a55fa2e50  0x00007f3a55fa394e  Yes         /lib64/libdl.so.2
0x00007f3a55cf54e0  0x00007f3a55d5c59a  Yes         /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
0x00007f3a5599d350  0x00007f3a55a08336  Yes         /lib64/libm.so.6
0x00007f3a55784ad0  0x00007f3a55794285  Yes         /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
0x00007f3a5556b8f0  0x00007f3a55576db1  Yes         /lib64/libpthread.so.0
0x00007f3a551b79f0  0x00007f3a55307b6f  Yes         /lib64/libc.so.6
0x00007f3a561a6af0  0x00007f3a561c2060  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007f3a44568d90  0x00007f3a445dbb1a  Yes         /node_modules/re2-applic/node_modules/re2/build/Release/re2.node
0x00007f3a3fc2ac80  0x00007f3a3fdcd7d0  Yes (*)     /webapp/node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node
0x00007f3a44137b30  0x00007f3a4414163a  Yes (*)     /webapp/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/napi-v3/bcrypt_lib.node
0x00007f3a3ebcf330  0x00007f3a3ebe0e32  Yes (*)     /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libz.so.1
0x00007f3a3e515a10  0x00007f3a3e54a3c6  Yes         /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libgobject-2.0.so.0
0x00007f3a3e1edb30  0x00007f3a3e270e69  Yes         /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libglib-2.0.so.0
0x00007f3a3cc74cc0  0x00007f3a3cd70615  Yes         /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libgio-2.0.so.0
0x00007f3a3c124230  0x00007f3a3c1271bc  Yes         /lib64/librt.so.1
0x00007f3a239bea00  0x00007f3a239c640e  Yes (*)     /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libffi.so.7
0x00007f3a237792b0  0x00007f3a237a2131  Yes         /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libpcre.so.1
0x00007f3a22bd20b0  0x00007f3a22bd2f85  Yes         /node_modules/pdf-generator/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
0x00007f3a229ba980  0x00007f3a229c9162  Yes         /lib64/libresolv.so.2
(*): Shared library is missing debugging information.
(gdb)
```

Comment: What is the output from `(gdb) info shared` ? Please edit your question with that info.

Comment: That's already there Sir, in the grey box..

Comment: "That's already there" -- no it's _not_.

Comment: I did the backtrace on the coredump again, Added it to the question. I hope you're asking for the same. Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: I didn't ask for "output from bt", I asked for output from "info shared".

Comment: @EmployedRussian added "info shared" output from gdb...Thanks!